# Xcode crashes when accessing parts of Preferences menu

Tags: xcode, crash

So I was having an issue where anytime I accessed the Account tab, the Behaviors tab or the Git part of the Source Control tab in the Xcode Preferences menu, it would crash the whole application.  The crash was immediate and I would get this as part of the error log.

> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
> Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4 Terminating Process:
> exc handler [1309]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now, I actually found out the reason for the crash and am posting this just because I would have liked to have had a post like this.  The reason is because I was opening those tabs of that menu on a connected monitor.  When I moved the menu over to my Macbook's built in screen, the menu worked as normal.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue on external Apple monitor. If I use xCode on laptop screen, all good.
but have crash immediately after clicking Xcode > Preferences